# altered comments by moderators?

Tags: discussion, comments

Is it that modes are altering comments?

Thus A,C, Eb is correct and A,C,D# would be not the best. But if you construct dim7 chords you can build an dim7 on each tone of the tetrad A,C,Eb,Gb and transform this chord to D#,F#,A,C and all other enharmonic exchanged chords. That's why the dim7-chords are useful for modulation. – Albrecht Hügli 19 mins ago

Tim commented 18 mins later @Albrecht Hügli: A,C,E is no diminished chord ...
(but this comment has been deleted, could be that Tim missred something)

@Tim: did I say something different? – Albrecht Hügli 5 mins ago    Edit

@AlbrechtHügli - yes, before you altered the comment! – Tim 3 mins ago

I can't alter a comment of 14 min ago ... But something irritates me: I don't remember that I had written would be not the best. Is there a ghostwriter in here? – Albrecht Hügli 1 min ago

It might be that I had a typo and wrote A,C,E (what I don't believe)

But I trust Tim and I also can't remember that I wrote **A,C,D# would be not the best**

Comment: Albrecht, sometimes I look at a comment I wrote and realize, "Hold on, that's not what I meant to say!"  But when I try to edit it, I fail, because the system thinks 5 minutes have passed already.  Sometimes that happens to me when only 4 minutes have gone by!  I want to tell you about a trick you can use if that ever happens to you.  Copy the text of the comment, delete the comment, and start fresh by copying the original text into the new comment.  Then you can make your changes before submitting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mods can alter other's comments, but there's almost never a reason to. The only valid reason is to edit out an abusive or offensive comment that still have salvageable content which I think I've only ever seen done once. We do have a very basic paper trail and can do some digging. For that comment, there are only two edits both by you. This was the first revision:

> Thus A,C, Eb is correct and A,C,D# would be not the best. But if you construct dim7 chords you can take e

And this was the second:

> Thus A,C, Eb is correct and A,C,D# would be not the best. But if you construct dim7 chords you can build an dim7 on each tone of the tetrad A,C,Eb,Gb and transform this chord to D#,F#,A,C and all other enharmonic exchanged chords. That's why the dim7-chords are useful for modulation.

---

On a side note, comments in general are for a very specific purpose of critiquing the post and requesting clarification and for the most part should be viewed as temporary sticky notes that can be removed when the change requested is made. We've been getting a lot of comments flagging off topic discussions which have been deleted and will keep being deleted. Discussions are fine, but the chat rooms should be used for them.

Comment: I see! Then the explanation: I was writing something *Thus A,C, Eb is correct and A,C,D# would be not the best. But if you construct dim7 chords you can take e ...* and my comment has been sent before the sentence was finished may be I’ve touched the enter key - this happens more often. But I surely didn’t mean to write a,c,e. Well this was not the problem to me, but I didn’t remember there was a problem and surely not a typo of mine or a bug in may brain - what happens sometimes. So I’d like to apologize to Tim. I couldn’t explain his comment but now all seems to be clear thanks to you, Dom.

Comment: My comment was indeed based on the 1st revision, which I think was added to *after* my comment. No apology needed! I'm a little concerned that mods can alter comments. Whilst this may be necessary, a note from that mod would be a polite addition.

Answer (score 3):

As our expert Dom has confirmed, it seems no editing has been observed from the moderation team. Thanks for the sleuth work! *(Cool fact about comments: They can be edited by the user as many times as is desired until five minutes have elapsed from the moment the comment was posted in its original form.)*

I know the problem's been largely resolved by now, but I feel obligated to point the following out for the more general case:

Looking at this from a computer systems approach, **if an incident seems to be occurring from your end, but you do not recall the actions, it is possible that your security has been in some way compromised.** It's not very likely in this case (who would want to hack an SE account just to edit some random comment?), but perhaps someone could have logged into your account and performed actions that you would not recall. Let's hope this never becomes an issue here on SE, but login security breaches are one possible explanation as to how inexplicable things could seem to come from an account that denies responsibility for an action.

Comment: Yes, it’s solved. :) But it’s good to know that mods actually can change comments too.